# PowerShell script to calculate the memory usage per user

Tags: powershell

We have an environment of 240 VMs. Clients are using ICA/RDP connection to connect to these servers. Sometimes users are hogging the memory and causing the slowing and crash on that particular server.

I would like to have a PowerShell script to calculate the memory usage for each user connected to the server. I spent hours and hours searching and trying different scripts but was not successful.

Some scripts giving me the working sets value using `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process` and `GetOwner()`. but the calculation is not correct.

What I need is exactly the format that I can see in the users tab in Task Manager. The main information which I need is the memory usage, but it would be nice to have the disk and CPU usage per user as well.

Here is the code which i am using. When i run this script after a minute or two It returns an error which says $.GetOwner() can not be found and in another line it gives me the user name which utilizing the memory more than the others but the calculation is not correct when i compare it with TaskManager user's tab.

```
$h = @{}
get-wmiobject win32_process | foreach { 
    $u = $_.getowner().user;
    if ( $u -ne $null)
    {
        if ( !$h.ContainsKey($u)  )
        {
            $h.add( $u, $_.WS);
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $h.item($u) = $h.item($u) + $_.WS;
        } 
    }
}  
$h.GetEnumerator() | sort value -desc
```

Comment: Show us the code and explain how the calculation is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Please check the code on my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
get-wmiobject win32_process | 
    select @{N='User';E={$_.getowner().user}}, WorkingSetSize  |
        group user | 
            select Name, @{N='CPU';E={($_.Group.WorkingSetSize  | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum / 1Mb  }}
```

Comment: Thanks Esperanto57. That works good and I've changed it a little bit to show the highest memory usage for a single user.

Answer (score 0):

```
gwmi win32_process | 
    select @{N='User';E={$_.getowner().user}},WorkingSetSize | 
        group User | select Name,@{N='RAM';E={[math]::Round(($_.Group.WorkingSetSize | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum/1MB) }} | 
            sort RAM -Descending | select -first 1 ;
```